# Individually Play/Pause multiple HTML5 videos

Tags: javascript, html5-video

Can anyone help me re-write the following code to work without using ID's, so that I can use this for multiple videos on a single page? Thank you in advance!!

```
HTML MARKUP

<div id="video-container">
    <video id="video" width="640" height="365" src="https://d3vv6lp55qjaqc.cloudfront.net/items/3V3g280Q1z441P071g3E/tnt-lidcap-web.mp4" type="video/mp4" autoplay loop muted></video>
    <div id="video-controls">
        <button id="play-pause" type="button" aria-label="toggle pause play">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 120 120" width="120" height="120">
              <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="60" fill="#000" fill-opacity=".5" />
              <path stroke="#fff" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="10" d="M74.933 33v54M45.067 33v54" id="pauseIcon" class="video-pause" style="visibility: visible" />
              <path fill="#fff" stroke="#fff" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="8" d="M54 33L54 87 81 60z" id="playIcon" class="video-play" style="visibility: hidden" />
            </svg>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
JAVASCRIPT (WORKS FOR SINGLE VIDEO)
window.onload = function() {

  var video = document.getElementById("video");
  var playButton = document.getElementById("play-pause");
  var pauseIcon = document.getElementById("pauseIcon");
  var playIcon = document.getElementById("playIcon");

    playButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        if (video.paused == true) {
            video.play();
            pauseIcon.style.visibility ="visible";
            playIcon.style.visibility ="hidden";
        } else {
            video.pause();
            pauseIcon.style.visibility ="hidden";
            playIcon.style.visibility ="visible";
        }
    });
}
```

```
Here is a link to my current working CodePen as well:
https://codepen.io/jhughes1006/pen/yZPVGo
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "_**individually**_ play/pause videos"?

Comment: If I have 5 videos on the page, I want to be able to play/pause them separately from each other.

For example:
Video 1 can be playing, and I can pause Video 2 and Video 1 is not effected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can substitute `class` for each `id` and use `.querySelectorAll()` to perform the same task.

```
onload = e => {
  const containers = document.querySelectorAll('.video-container'):
  containers.forEach(container => {
    const video = container.querySelector('video');
    const playButton = container.querySelector('button');
    playButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
    // do stuff
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Do I have to place the code in a `for loop` to be able to use `.querySelectorAll`?

Comment: @JoannaHughes You can use `.forEach()` method of `NodeList`. See updated post.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else's future reference, here is the new working code for multiple videos based on the answer given by @guest271314

```
onload = function onload(e) {
    var containers = document.querySelectorAll(".video-container");
    containers.forEach(function(container) {
        var video = container.querySelector("video");
        var playButton = container.querySelector("button");
        var pauseIcon = container.querySelector(".pause-icon");
        var playIcon = container.querySelector(".play-icon");
        playButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            if (video.paused == true) {
                video.play();
                pauseIcon.style.visibility ="visible";
                playIcon.style.visibility ="hidden";
            } else {
                video.pause();
                pauseIcon.style.visibility ="hidden";
                playIcon.style.visibility ="visible";
            }
        });
    });
};
```